# .NET Unit test for requestedExecutionLevel

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Need to test for `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />` in app.manifest.
I need to be sure, that app will have admin rights.
Need NUnit scenario written in C# .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needing to do exactly what you did I finally developed the following given your "just read the xml" approach. Note that in order for this to work properly I also had to **change my testsettings** file to manually **deploy the app.manifest file** so that it would be there to read.

```
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Proper_Permissions_Set_In_app_manifest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var expected = "requireAdministrator";
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(TestContext.TestDeploymentDir, "app.manifest")))
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load(reader.BaseStream);
            var node = doc.Descendants("{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3}requestedExecutionLevel").First();
            var attribute = node.Attribute("level");

            // Act
            var actual = attribute.Value;

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps someone else...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can't perform such a test with NUnit.

NUnit performs unit tests on classes, not on executables. Although there is nothing to test in your case. Your statement in app.manifest grants that the application can be only executed with highest privileges where UAC is active.

If you don't trust me, try by yourself. Set UAC at different levels (Windows 7) or toggle it (Vista) and see!

Comment: Yes you are right, but you missunderstud me. I just need to parse app.manifest XML and find out <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" /> is existing in that XML. But i dont know how.